# Specific search on twitter using tweetsharp

Tags: c#, twitter, tweepy, tweetsharp, twitter-client

```
TwitterService vice = new TwitterService();
           var tweeting = vice.Search("#Ghaza", 100);
           List<TwitterSearchStatus> resultList = new List<TwitterSearchStatus>(tweeting.Statuses);
           foreach (var twt in resultList)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(resultList);
           }
```

It give me output like

```
System.Collection.Generic.List '1[TweetSharp.TwitterSearchStatus]
```

its not returning me tweets even my code run without error

Comment: looks like it returned a list of one TwitterSearchStatus

Comment: but why it not display the tweet

Comment: @AnumKhan, when you debug the app, what is the type of tweeting?

Comment: I want it in json form , but result which i get is displayed in question

Comment: The text of the tweet is contained in twt.Text. I think your loop body should be Console.WriteLine(twt.Text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(twt.Text);
```

use this in your loop . it works .